# Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear(); Does NOT Work

Tags: c#

I have a Chart which gets few scores from my database (SQL Server) and it shows them all completely in correct form as you see in this picture:

[image: First Image]

but when I want to show another scores in the chart it will add new chart to old one ( I mean it keeps old points and new points will be added to old ones ) as you see in this picture:

[image: Second Image]

I don't want to keep old points and I want to clear them all to prepare my chart for new points !

I've already tried these methods but they do not work :

1. Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
2. Chart1.Series.Clear();
   Chart1.Series.Add("Series1");

*I tried these codes in first of all codes so there is no problem about Arrangement

I really Appreciate if you have any idea

Comment: No need to Add a Series when one already exists.  All you need to to add a new array of X/Y values to existing chart.

Comment: I assure you that Points.Clear does work. So the error is in your code. Maybe you mix up charts or references or series or series indexing or what not. We can't know because we can't see.